# React provider pattern in other languages

Tags: python, c#, reactjs, design-patterns, architectural-patterns

Sorry for this question

I'm at the process of learning react in a good way and days ago when I finally get how the contexts and providers works on my mind I just fell in love with this technique.

Do you know if there is a pattern that can be applied to other languages like java, c# or python? or if there is a framework or library for working with that on these language

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Did you try searching for something like "programming design patterns" in you favourite search engine? I think most patterns can be used in all general purpose languages.

Comment: a generic question, but i answer the `python` tag here: https://www.fullstackpython.com/react.html